# All JMS messages acknowledged although I have only acknowledged one

Tags: jms

I have created a producer with transaction `false` and `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` that put 99 messages on the queue.

I created a consumer for the same queue with a different session and transacted `false` and `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`.

I did not acknowledge the first message and acknowledged the remaining 98 messages.

When I looked at the queue I expected to see 1 message pending / 1 on queue, but to my surprise I see all 99 messages dequeued.

Can someone please point out where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the expected behavior as dictated by the JMS specification. Section 4.4.11 titled "Message Acknowledgment" of the JMS 1.1 spec states:

> CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE - With this option, a client acknowledges a
> message by calling the message’s `acknowledge` method. **Acknowledging a
> consumed message automatically acknowledges the receipt of all messages
> that have been delivered by its session.** [emphasis added]

Some JMS brokers offer extended acknowledge modes (e.g. [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/pre-acknowledge.html#individual-acknowledge) and [ActiveMQ "Classic"](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQSession.html#INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE)) which may be helpful in this situation.

Comment: I don't have required points to upvote the answer, hence I have written a comment

Comment: No. It says votes cast by reputation less than 15 are recorded but not shown